# Convert byte[] to UInt16.

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, type-conversion

I have a 2d array of UInt16s which I've converted to raw bytes - I would like to take those bytes and convert them back into the original 2D array. I've managed to do this with a 2d array of doubles, but I can't figure out how to do it with UInt16.

Here's my code:

```
UInt16[,] dataArray; 
//This array is populated with this data:
[4 6 2]
[0 2 0]
[1 3 4]

long byteCountUInt16Array = dataArray.GetLength(0) * dataArray.GetLength(1) * sizeof(UInt16);

var bufferUInt16 = new byte[byteCountUInt16Array];
Buffer.BlockCopy(newUint16Array, 0, bufferUInt16, 0, bufferUInt16.Length);


//Here is where I try to convert the values and print them out to see if the values are still the same:

UInt16[] originalUInt16Values = new UInt16[bufferUInt16.Length / 8];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    originalUInt16Values[i] = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bufferUInt16, i * 8);
    Console.WriteLine("Values: " + originalUInt16Values[i]);
}
```

The print statement does not show the same values as the original 2d array. I'm pretty new to coding with bytes and UInt16 so most of this I'm learning in the process.

*Also, I know the last chunk of my code isn't putting values into a 2d array like the original array - right now I'm just trying to print out the values to see if they even match the original data.

Comment: `/ 8`, `* 8`- why 8 and not sizeof(UInt16) which is 2? Carry over from `double` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is just to cast UInt16[,]->Byte, and then Byte->UInt16 you can do another Block copy, which is very fast at run-time, code should look like this:

```
UInt16[,] dataArray = new UInt16[,] {
    {4, 6, 2},
    {0, 2, 0},
    {1, 3, 4}
};
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value[" + i + ", " + j + "] = " + dataArray[j,i]);
    }
}
long byteCountUInt16Array = dataArray.GetLength(0) * dataArray.GetLength(1) * sizeof(UInt16);

var bufferUInt16 = new byte[byteCountUInt16Array];

Buffer.BlockCopy(dataArray, 0, bufferUInt16, 0, bufferUInt16.Length);

//Here is where I try to convert the values and print them out to see if the  values are still the same:

UInt16[] originalUInt16Values = new UInt16[bufferUInt16.Length / 2];
Buffer.BlockCopy(bufferUInt16, 0, originalUInt16Values, 0, BufferUInt16.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
     //originalUInt16Values[i] = BitConverter.ToUInt16(bufferUInt16, i * 8);
     Console.WriteLine("Values---: " + originalUInt16Values[i]);
}
```

by the way, you only divided each UInt16 into two bytes, so you should calculate your new size dividing by two, not eight

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Do you know if there is anything in the byte[] that would tell me the dimensions of the original 2D array? If all I have are the bytes, then is it possible to know that they originally came from a 2D array? I created a new post for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693214/convert-byte-to-original-2d-array

Answer (score 3):

Addressing the title of your question (Convert byte[] to UInt16):

```
UInt16 result = (UInt16)BitConverter.ToInt16(yourByteArray, startIndex = 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The program

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UInt16[,] dataArray = new ushort[,]{ {4,6,2}, {0,2,0}, {1,3,4}}; 
        //This array is populated with this data:

        long byteCountUInt16Array = dataArray.GetLength(0) * dataArray.GetLength(1) * sizeof(UInt16);

        var byteBuffer = new byte[byteCountUInt16Array];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(dataArray, 0, byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);

        for(int i=0; i < byteBuffer.Length; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("byteBuf[{0}]= {1}", i, byteBuffer[i]);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Byte buffer len: {0} data array len: {1}", byteBuffer.Length, dataArray.GetLength(0)* dataArray.GetLength(1));
        UInt16[] originalUInt16Values = new UInt16[byteBuffer.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < byteBuffer.Length; i+=2)
        {
            ushort _a = (ushort)( (byteBuffer[i]) | (byteBuffer[i+1]) << 8);
            originalUInt16Values[i/2] = _a;
            Console.WriteLine("Values: " + originalUInt16Values[i/2]);
        }
    }
```

Outputs

```
byteBuf[0]= 4
byteBuf[1]= 0
byteBuf[2]= 6
byteBuf[3]= 0
byteBuf[4]= 2
byteBuf[5]= 0
byteBuf[6]= 0
byteBuf[7]= 0
byteBuf[8]= 2
byteBuf[9]= 0
byteBuf[10]= 0
byteBuf[11]= 0
byteBuf[12]= 1
byteBuf[13]= 0
byteBuf[14]= 3
byteBuf[15]= 0
byteBuf[16]= 4
byteBuf[17]= 0
Byte buffer len: 18 data array len: 9
Values: 4
Values: 6
Values: 2
Values: 0
Values: 2
Values: 0
Values: 1
Values: 3
Values: 4
```

You see that a `ushort`, aka `UInt16` is stored in a byte-order in which `4 = 0x04 0x00`, which is why I chose the conversion formula

```
            ushort _a = (ushort)( (byteBuffer[i]) | (byteBuffer[i+1]) << 8);
```

Which will grab the `byte` at index `i` and take the next `byte` at `i+1` and left shift it by the size of a byte (8 bits) to make up the 16 bits of a `ushort`. In orhter words, `ushort _a = 0x[second byte] 0x[first byte]`, which is then repeated. This conversion code is specific for the endianess of the machine you are on and thus non-portable.

Also I fixed the error where the `byteBuffer` array was to big because it was multiplied with factor `8`. A `ushort` is double the size of a `byte`, thus we only need factor 2 in the array length.

Answer (score 0):

Your casting up so you should be able to do things implicitly

```
var list = new List<byte> { 1, 2 , 
var uintList = new List<UInt16>();

//Cast in your select
uintList = list.Select(x => (UInt16)x).ToList();
```